# How to dynamically locate a Gem's view paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Say I have a gem, for instance, called "foo" in my application. Let's say foo has a view directory structure like so:

```
foo
|-- app
    |-- views
        |-- foo
            |-- posts
            +-- users
```

How can I, from within my Rails app, return the views paths for the Gem "foo", without knowing anything about the gem's directory structure? Essentially, I'd like to return:

```
/gem/path/foo/app/views/foo/posts
/gem/path/foo/app/views/foo/users
```

Comment: A gem creator might put views in folder `hidden/secret/looks` and load them from there. It looks like the only option is to reverse engeneer the sources.

Comment: May be we can help you better if you state exactly what you are trying to achieve like what gem or what view from what gem you are trying to use…

Comment: @j03w I'm building a utility gem at https://github.com/KyleMacey/geode. Right now I'm parsing file paths, but I'm looking for something more consistent. You can see how I'm parsing now at https://github.com/KyleMacey/geode/blob/master/lib/generators/geode/geode_generator.rb#L27